# How to delete 0's after last 1's

Tags: python, pandas

I have written code that deletes all the rows after the first occurrence of value 1 in target but I want it to happen after the last.

[image]

I want to delete the 0's that come after the last 1, per user_id.

How can I change this piece of code to get that?

`df = df[df.groupby('user_id')['target'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().eq(1).cumsum().eq(0))]`

Comment: Hi Michal, please have a look at [How to create a MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/12242625) and provide some data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution remove `shift` and for remove `0` from back per groups change ordering of values in group by `iloc[::-1]`:

```
mask = (df.groupby('user_id')['target']
          .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::-1].eq(1).cumsum().ne(0).iloc[::-1]))
df = df[mask]
```

For better performance is possible use if only `0` and `1` values in target:

```
mask = df.iloc[::-1].groupby('user_id')['target'].cumsum().ne(0).iloc[::-1]
df = df[mask]
```

If also another values like `0,1` use:

```
mask = (df.iloc[::-1]
          .assign(new = lambda x: x['target'].eq(1))
          .groupby('user_id')['new']
          .cumsum().ne(0)
          .iloc[::-1])
df = df[mask]
```

If need avoid remove only `0` groups use:

```
mask = df.groupby('user_id')['target'].transform('any')

mask1 = (df.iloc[::-1]
          .assign(new = lambda x: x['target'].eq(1))
          .groupby('user_id')['new']
          .cumsum().ne(0)
          .iloc[::-1])
df = df[~mask | mask1]
```